# Can the word "since" be used in this way?

Tags: grammar

In terms of academic achievements, he is within the top one percent of students since the establishment of this department.

Comment: I can't succinctly explain exactly why, but it seems to me that when you use adverbial ***since** [some point in past time]* like this, the main verb should be ***Present Perfect*** - thus, it's *I **have been** in the top one percent of students **since** I started in this school* (not *I **am** in the top...*). Personally, I don't like ***since*** being used in a true Past Tense context, so *I **was** in the top one percent **since** I joined the class* doesn't work for me, regardless of whether I'm *still* in the class at time of utterance.

Comment: It sounds awkward to me. I can't quite work out why though! I'd probably say something like say something like "...he's within in the top 1% of all students in the history of this department."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "since" to mean *from* a specific point in time. For example, "*I have felt ill since I ate that sushi*". So, from an English grammar point of view, your example is fine. It helps establish that the person is not just in the top 1% of *current* students, but of all students, ever.

Comment: I agree, but I think the sentence would be a little easier to understand if it was "
.. top one percent of *all* students since ...".